# Return type to assign to val for RDDs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am playing around with spark code to know more about shuffling. I wrote the following code to see how are stages formed if there is a `if-else` statement. I have declared `val result` so that the result could be assigned to it later in the `if` statement. But I am not sure about the return type to assign to it.

Is there an abstract class that goes with all the RDDs?

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("spark shuffle")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val d = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000).map(i => (i%1000, i))
val x = d.reduceByKey(_+_)

val count = 1
val result: RDD // What is the correct return type here?

if(count == 1)
  {
    result= d.rightOuterJoin(x)
    result.collect()

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

d is a RDD[(Int, Int)]

Then doing a reduce by key gives the same thing but reduced down

Doing a right outer join then gives you RDD of (Int, (Option[Int], Int)) - ie for each key the L and R value (with the L option being optional if not there)

So doing a collect gives you an array of the same thing

The API documentation is not easy to follow for all these functions, there is a lot of generic types, and a lot of implicit types. I would recommend that you either use an IDE which will hint the types for you, or else use a tool that gives you a console that you can try snippets in.

Comment: I ran the code with `val result: RDD[(Int, (Option[Int], Int))]`. But it shows me two errors
`Error:(14, 9) only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members
    val d3: RDD[(Int, (Option[Int], Int))]`


`Error:(17, 11) reassignment to val
        d3= d.rightOuterJoin(d1)`

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid assignment to `var` (it should be `var`, not `val`)

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("spark shuffle")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val d = sc.parallelize(0 until 1000).map(i => (i%1000, i))
val x = d.reduceByKey(_+_)

val count = 1

if (count == 1) {
    d.rightOuterJoin(x).collect()
}
```